# Arrange text in text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to fix the box on the right side (sometimes the same problem will occur to the left box too) . I tried using word=WRAP but it seems like that not the correct method. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

[box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ircg.png)

```
totalskt_box = tk.Text(master=window, height=1, width =8, bg="white", 
relief='solid', wrap=WORD)
totalskt_box.place(x = 790, y =670) # total skt

totalchg_box = tk.Text(master=window, height=1, width =8, bg="white", 
relief='solid', wrap=WORD)
totalchg_box.place(x = 1240, y =670) # total skt
```

Comment: Your code will not produce the `Text` boxes as shown in the image link because you have set `width=8` (ie 8 characters width) and `height=1` (only one line visible).  BTW to fix the right box in the image link, set the `width` to long enough to hold the lines without wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The method `WRAP=word` allows you to cut the tex by word and not by character. To place the text on the right side, use `totalskt_box.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='e')`

the `grid` method place a widget. You can use `column=...` to set the column, `row=...` to set the row, `padx=...` or `padx=(..., ...)` and `pady=...` or `pady=(..., ...)` to set space around the widget, `sticky=...` to stick the widget on one side. Use `'n'`, `'e'`, `'s'`, `'w'`, or `'ne'`, `'se'`, `'so'`, `'no'` (in reference to the coordinate points).